# Can not check out specific branch

Tags: git

We have a repository with "develop" as default branch. I tried cloning the branch using the following command:

```
$ git init
$ git clone --single-branch --branch develop https://bitbucket.agile.aaa.com/scm/proj1/proj1.git
```

After it finished,

```
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        proj1/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Why it showed "On branch master" instead of "On branch develop"? the command just cloned a repository, not checked out any files, why it showed "Untracked files"

```
$ git checkout develop
error: pathspec 'develop' did not match any file(s) known to git.
$ git branch -a
$
```

The "develop" branch seemed to be non-existent.

Comment: There has not output after using `$ git branch -a`. Could you please check again to make sure that the `develop` branch exists on repo `https://bitbucket.agile.aaa.com`?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. it was simple: no need to run git init, but do need to cd to the repo dir before running git status or checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `git clone` only created a new local branch `develop`, but did not actually *switch* to that branch.  To switch to the new `develop` branch, use `git checkout`:

```
git checkout develop
```

To first verify that the clone worked, you may use `git branch -a`.  Then look for a *tracking* branch called something like `origin/develop`.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I ran the two commands. But it seemed the "develop" branch did not exist. I updated my question with the output.

Answer (score 0):

Before, `clone` command:

> proj1

Then, you typed `clone --branch --single-branch --branch develop...`

> proj1/
> |- proj1/

Maybe, you were wrong root folder.

In currently repo, you can add remote via command:

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git`

And then checkout develop branch:

`git checkout -b develop origin/develop`